# Need assistance Joining Two Tables

Tags: php, sql, join, phpmyadmin

i have been unable to understand how to join 2 tables together so i may grab info from one and sort by another. It actually looks like the first table actually creates a "row" variable to use later. I tried asking before but it didn't help so im going to try and explain better and maybe il learn something... Im hoping someone here will be able to help me make a working code that will do this for me. My current line of code i am using is

```
$sql3 = new db;
$sql3->db_Select(DB_TABLE_ROSTER_TEAM_MEMBERS, "*", "team_id = ".intval($row1['team_id'])." ORDER BY member_team_order");
```

However i need it to order by a diff field on another table. on the other table it would look like this

```
$sql3 = new db;
$sql3->db_Select(DB_TABLE_ROSTER_MEMBERS, "*", ORDER BY member_status");
```

Please note that all i need the other table for is to order by the member_status.

Im guessing this is possible but the join command seems very complicated and i cant wrap my head around it alone. so im looking for help from the experts(you).
Im doing my best to explain but If there is any info i can give to help please let me know.

This code im trying to modify is way above me but i do like a challenge...

### Table Structures-

**Table Name-** roster_team_members
**Fields-** member_id, member_name, team_id, team_name, game_id, game_name, member_team_status, text_color, member_team_order

**Table Name-** roster_members
**Fields-** member_id, nickname, real_name, external_image, active_external_image, member_status,leader_status,leader_order, member_application_date

UPDATE-

```
$sql3 = new db;
$sql3  ="select t.* from #roster_team_members as t ";
$sql3 .="inner join #roster_members on t.member_id =m.member_id ";
$sql3 .="where t.team_id=".intval($row1['team_id']);
$sql3 .="order by m.member_status";
$db->db_select_gen($sql3); 
while($row3 = $db->db_Fetch()) {
```

and im getting a Fatal Error-
Fatal error: Call to a member function db_select_gen() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\DTK_Testing_Site\e107_plugins\jbroster_menu\jbroster.php on line 523

line 523 is the $db->db_select_gen($sql3); line. any ideas?

UPDATE2-
replaced the above with this-

```
$sql3 = new db;
$sql3 -> db_Select_gen("select t.* from ".e107_jbclan_roster_team_members." as t 
inner join ".e107_jbclan_roster_members." on t.member_id =m.member_id 
WHERE t.team_id=@team_id
ORDER BY m.member_status") or die(mysql_error());
```

and now im just getting these small errors like... Unknown column 'm.member_id' in 'on clause'
im so close to finishing this. any more help would be awesome...

```
while($row3 = $db->db_Fetch()) {
```

**IV DONE IT!!!!**
I couldnt have done it without you Guilhem Hoffmann. Thank you so much... Finally this issue is resolved and i can live my life again lol. thx stackoverflow.com!!!!

Comment: pleas post the structure of each table.

Comment: What is your function db_select ? Could we modify it? Give us the full structure of your tables because you need to make a join but we need to know the keys name

Comment: @Guilhem Hoffmann Im using e107(CMS) so im not sure what there setup is. where would i look to find this? UPDATE- this may be what your looking for- http://e107coders.org/e107_plugins/faq/faq.php?cat.6.5

Comment: Ok will have a look i gave you the full sql request but I need to convert to e107 syntax

Comment: that would be sooo awesome. thank you.

Comment: Is you new db instruction working?

Comment: i dont believe so. its saying its causing the fatal error.

Comment: I have a test server up if you were interested in helping further. Prob easier h=to help figure out how to integrate this with e107. just a thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

You want to do join btw your two tables something like

```
select t.*
from roster_team_members as t, roster_members a m
-- you grab the member with liaising team record and member one
where t.member_id =m.member_id and t.team_id = @team_id
-- you use the member status in member table to do the sort
order by m.member_status
```

With the inner syntax

```
select t.*
from roster_team_members as t
-- you grab the member with liaising team record and member 
inner join roster_members on t.member_id =m.member_id
where t.team_id=@team_id
-- you use the member status in member table to do the sort
order by m.member_status
```

In Php

```
 <?php
      // in the doc, you can find that # is used to select the current database scheme
      $sql  ="select t.* from #roster_team_members as t ";
      $sql .="inner join #roster_members on t.member_id =m.member_id ";
      $sql .="where t.team_id=".intval($row1['team_id']);
      $sql .="order by m.member_status";
      $db->db_select_gen($sql);
```

Comment: I still need the 
"team_id = ".intval($row1['team_id'])." 
to be used as well. so how would that get integrated into the join?

Comment: I updated the sql to show what should be done exactly. I tried to find the correct syntax with e107 but now you have the main concept

Comment: thank you Guilhem Hoffmann, Il try and get this converted into somthing that e107 can understand(maybe il post in the e107 forums lol). again thank you for all your help. hopefully i can get this to work.

Comment: I do have a small question tho... which one of the codes do i need? the first or second one lol.

Comment: The both syntax give the same result, maybe you entry point for e107 search would be inner join mostly than using 2 tables but nothing sure. E107 forum is a really good idea

Comment: oh ok kool thanks. i found the e107 syntax here- http://wiki.e107.org/index.php?title=Db#db_Select.28.29
so il start there and try and convert it there. thx..